# ¿Cuál es la lista completa de las preposiciones reconocidas por la RAE?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, preposiciones

Aún recuerdo la lista de preposiciones que me enseñaron en el colegio:

> A, ante, bajo, cabe, con, contra, de, desde, en, entre, hacia, hasta, para, por, según, sin, so, sobre, tras.

De estas, algunas ya eran arcaicas y así nos lo avisaban, como *[cabe](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6PPZNlz)* 'cerca de, junto a' y *[so](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y3Da92X)* 'bajo, debajo de'. Desde entonces se han introducido en la lista a aprender algunas nuevas, como *[mediante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OkJXvGN)* 'por medio de' y *[vía](https://dle.rae.es/?id=biXBkO2)* 'por, pasando por'.

Sin embargo, todavía encuentro a veces en el diccionario algunas que me descolocan, como la siguiente, a la que llegué buscando el significado de *[pardiez](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RuJ78XP)*:

> **[par<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Rp05ibZ)**
>
> Del lat. *per*.
>
> 1. prep. En fórmulas de juramento, **por**. *Par Dios.*

Como estoy seguro de que aún se me escaparán muchas, pregunto: ¿cuál es la lista actual y completa de las preposiciones reconocidas por la RAE en el DLE? Nótese que busco palabras simples, no locuciones preposicionales.

Bonus: ¿Qué otras preposiciones hubo antaño que hayan sido ya eliminadas del DLE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Marco la respuesta como *community wiki* para que os sintáis libres de añadir más elementos a la lista, enlaces, frases de ejemplo, etc.

---

Filtrando las preposiciones en la búsqueda avanzada de Enclave, y eliminando las locuciones, me aparecen las siguientes como formando parte del DLE (se resaltan en negrita las que forman parte del núcleo de preposiciones reconocidas por las diferentes gramáticas):

- **[a](https://dle.rae.es/?id=003Ov93)** / [ad](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0gW1LAE) (desuso)
- [allende](https://dle.rae.es/?id=1vQAJQ3)
- **[ante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2lpQu7Z)**
- [aprés](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3ImvJtF) (desuso)
- *[apud](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3KgDYUe)*

  - Ejemplo: *Una composición retórica de este género puede leerse íntegra apud al-Hurayfis (siglo XIV de J. C.), pp. 102-8.*
- [aquende](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3MMIoxE) (poco usada)
- **[bajo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4oyrC6G#JX96nUL)**
- **[cabe](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6PPZNlz)** (desuso) / [cabo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6S13ycd#GvzI9Tu) (desuso)
- [cara](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7NOG7x2#LhcIGsc) (desuso)
- [circa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9J5wSPG)
- [como](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9#LxQXBHt)
- **[con](https://dle.rae.es/?id=A5cH5M4)**
- **[contra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AWCzXfA)**
- [cuando](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BRprn7t)
- **[de](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BtFYznp)**
- [dejante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C5XUXA8)
- **[desde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Cmy8XSZ)** / [dende](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CBA4Xtf) (desuso) / [des](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CJrmi27) (desuso)
- [donde](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8FfJ0i) / [adonde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0o0QaKX) (coloquial)
- **[durante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EHqoAYN)**
- **[en](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EuPaWdO)**
- [enta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ff7chDy) (desuso)
- **[entre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FkNx2AZ)**
- [entro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FpN1x2H) (desuso)
- [escontra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GHlhNGM) (desuso)
- [foras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IDrlo4W) (desuso)
- **[hacia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JxHUqK9)**
- **[hasta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K2iXUid)** / [fasta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Hf6udW2) (desuso)
- **[mediante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OkJXvGN)**
- **[para](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Rp1CuT2)** / [pora](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TgN8StA) (desuso)
- **[por](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TgJ7yhD)** / [par](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Rp05ibZ)
- [salvante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=X8Wd42H) (poco usada)
- **[según](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XTC2Xzt)**
- **[sin](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XwHtfb4)** / [sen](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XYtQeep) (desuso)
- **[so](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y3Da92X)**
- **[sobre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y5lVqnD)**
- [sota](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YSJww8e) (desuso)
- **[tras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aOnVELH)**
- **[versus](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bfyaXi1)**
- **[vía](https://dle.rae.es/?id=biXBkO2#KQ4uGsN)**

Comment: De las que aparecen como en desuso conocía solo un par. Gracias @Charlie

Comment: ¿ *cuando* preposición? Sólo creo reconocerla como conjunción.

Comment: @Gustavson el diccionario cita los siguientes ejemplos en su uso como preposición: "Yo, cuando niño, vivía en Cáceres. Cuandola famosa catástrofe, todos fuimos solidarios."

Comment: Para mí sólo es una conjunción con elipsis verbal: *cuando (era) niño, cuando (ocurrió) la famosa catástrofe.* No me convence para nada su clasificación como preposición.

Comment: Lo mismo ocurre con "donde".

Comment: La palabra "conforme" por sí sola no es una preposición, sino una conjunción. Solo se usa como preposición en locuciones, que quedan fuera del ámbito de esta pregunta.

Comment: @Gustavson en la peli de Cars, en el doblaje para España dicen "¿Por qué no te tomas una latita de aceite donde Flo?", reflejando su uso como preposición.

Comment: Algunas de estas son meramente variaciones fonéticas (sen/sin, fasta/hasta, circa/cerca), tal vez debemos juntarlas en una línea.  Otras son variaciones dialectales que, por las razones parecidas, debemos juntar con la variante estándar (escontra/contra, dende/desde)

Comment: @guifa según el DLE, _contra_ y _escontra_ no parecen ser la misma preposición, dado que tienen significados diferentes. Por lo demás, estoy procediendo a modificar la respuesta según tu sugerencia (aunque recuerdo que la respuesta es CW, cualquier mejora que consideréis oportuna la podéis hacer sin preguntar).

Comment: @Charlie Es interesante que no lo definan de igual forma, ya que *contra* también tiene la misma acepción (*hacia* = *en dirección a*).  Tal vez en castellano *escontra* llegó a tener solo el significado de *hacia* mientras *contra* seguía con los demás (en asturiano, *escontra* alberga todos los significados, en portugués *escontra* se considera nada más una forma antigua de *contra*).  Sería interesante ver la entrada de *escontra* en el excelentísimo DELLA cuando salga el tomo con E para ver de dónde y por qué surgió el prefijo *es-*

Comment: En el campo chileno se usaba la expresión "denantes" y "en denante"(algunos decían "enenante") para referirse a algo ocurrido hacía poco rato.
También era frecuente decir que algo inconducente se había hecho "por nojar" ¿como abreviatura de "por no dejar"? para referirse a un esfuerzo o trabajo inútil.